# Nginx : whitelisting browsers

Tags: nginx, useragent

I'm trying to setup a whitelist of browsers allowed to visit a static website hosted by a nginx server.

I found in [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_browser_module.html) a reference to `modern_browser` directive.

It seems interesting but I still have some questions :
- How can I detect Chrome browser ? (let's say I want to detect Chrome 60 and Safari 11)
- How can I know if It's a mobile Chrome or Safari ?

Answer (score 1):

The modern_browser* directives are not just horribly outdated for today's practical purposes, they are no longer necessary today. You can just match the now-relevant browsers in a regex map.

Assuming you are doing this right now:

```
modern_browser_value "modern.";
ancient_browser_value "unpatched.";
modern_browser gecko 60;
index index.${modern_browser}html index.${ancient_browser}html index.html;
```

The following accomplishes similar matching, but allows more fine-grained control:

```
map $http_user_agent $browser_prefix {
   "~Mozilla/5.0 \(.+ rv:[6789][0-9]\.[0-9.]*\).* Firefox/[0-9.]*$" "modern."
   "~Mozilla/5.0 \(Android" "unpatched.";
   default "unpatched.";
}
index index.${browser_prefix}html index.html;
```

You can use the resulting `$variable` the same way, including outright access denial like

```
if ($browser_prefix = "unpatched.") {return 403;}
```

---

**Because your question mentions whitelisting, [here is a list of reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) people use browser-detection when they should not be doing that:**

- Work around Browser bugs

  - Usually a workaround that is much easier to maintain for the long term exists by changing markup or javascript. Usually the workaround is already mentioned in the respective browsers bug tracker
- Access control

  - If you wanted to abuse the User-Agent string as a password, you should have instead used Basic Authentication - it has similar security properties, yet was designed for such purposes and therefore much more reliable
- Detect browser features (e.g. is it capable of playing certain video codecs?)

  - You will not get the answer from the user agent string. Features get added to browser all the time, and this way you cannot tell whether the user has disabled already-shipped features or enabled not-yet-default features.